# Prolog pathfinder

Tags: prolog

I'm interested in pathfinder stuff and found a cool example on a site from 2011 but there isn't any explanation for the code. I understand what it does but don't understand how the steps work. So, for example these are the edges:

```
edge(1,2).
edge(1,4).
edge(2,4).
edge(3,6).
edge(3,7).
edge(4,3).
edge(4,5).
edge(5,6).
edge(5,7).
edge(6,5).
edge(7,5).
edge(8,6).
edge(8,7).
```

and with this I can tell if there is path between them:

```
path(X,Y,[X,Y]):- edge(X,Y).
path(X,Y,[X|Xs]):- edge(X,W), path(W,Y,Xs).
```

The output is something like this:

```
path(1,6,Xs).
Xs = [1,2,4,5,6];
Xs = [1,4,5,6];
...
```

But how does it exactly work?
What does [X,Y] do in the first line and what happens in the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crucial thing to understand in this example is how recursive predicates work. First of all, recursion always needs a *recursion step* (recursive use of the current predicate), and a *recursion anchor* (the step where the recursion stops). The resolution algorithm is a depth-first search, and whereever there are multiple options to choose from (i.e., a `;` or different rules or facts with the signature), the interpreter chooses from top to bottom and from left to right. To avoid infinite evaluations, the recursion anchor needs to be on the top like it is here, and the recursion step should be on the right of the second rule.

In the above example, the recursion stops when there is a direct edge between `X`and `Y`, because that's where the path ends. Keep in mind that the rules are implications from right to left. As the third parameter is an output argument (the result you want to get), it needs to be initialized first in the anchor. `[X,Y]` does that by starting it with a list that contains the last two elements of the path. The rule is equivalent to the following:

```
path(X,Y,Result):- edge(X,Y), Result = [X,Y].
```

The second rule aims to find intermediate path elements: It assumes there is an `edge(X,W)` to an intermediate element `W`, and then a path from `W` to `Y`. The interpreter will try every edge from `X` to possible `W`s. If there exists a path from a `W` to `Y`, there also is a path from `X` to `Y`, and the second rule becomes true for that step. The result of the recursive use to the predicate (the path list in the third parameter) will be `Xs`. So all that needs to be done in the current step is to add the `X` to the result list (`[X|Xs]`). Again, that is equivalent to:

```
path(X,Y,Result):- edge(X,W), path(W,Y,Xs), Result=[X|Xs].
```

Long story short: The resulting list is started with the last two elements in the recursion anchor, which then gets passed backwards through all recursive steps, and each step add its current `X` to the front to the list.

Of course recursion can still be infinite when there are cycles in the data (and paths) like in the example. If you want to avoid such cycles (and likely unwanted solutions such as paths where elements appear multiple times), you can keep track of the elements already visited:

```
path(X,Y,[X,Y],V):- \+member(X,V),\+member(Y,V),edge(X,Y).
path(X,Y,[X|Xs],V):- \+member(X,V),edge(X,W), path(W,Y,Xs,[X|V]).
```

In this solution, the list in the additional forth parameter collects the items already visited in an additional list. With `\+member(X,V)` it can be checked if the current `X` is already contained in `V`. There are other ways this can be implemented, for example by just using `V` as a result an reverting it in the anchor. `V` needs to be initialized in the query with an empty list:

```
?- path(1,6,R,[]).
R = [1, 2, 4, 3, 6] ;
R = [1, 2, 4, 3, 7, 5, 6] ;
...
```

Comment: *To avoid infinite evaluations,...* That is inaccurate. Try a path from 1 to 8...

Comment: @false you are right, I did't see the cycle there, which should have been handled by the predicate. I will extend the answer in a few minutes.